# Elastic Search not returning matched data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic search index ,mapping as below :

```
{
  "issues": {
    "mappings": {
      "issues": {
        "properties": {
          "captured_by": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "captured_on": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "updated_at": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          }
          "issue_org_states": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "assigned_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "dateOptionalTime"
              },
              "assigned_by": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "updated_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "dateOptionalTime"
              },
              "updated_by": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And populated one document as below :

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "issues",
        "_type": "issues",
        "_id": "13f3bf09-08cb-4464-b326-15872bdb0870",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "13f3bf09-08cb-4464-b326-15872bdb0870",
          "description": "Sloppy paint job",
          "captured_on": "2017-10-09T09:24:01.928Z",
          "captured_by": 1,
          "updated_at": "2017-10-09T12:47:22.982Z",
          "issue_org_states": [
            {
              "updated_at": "2017-10-09T12:47:22.982Z",
              "updated_by": 1,
              "assigned_at": "2017-10-09T12:47:22.982Z",
              "assigned_by": 1879048240
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want do query on path "issues.issue_org_states" on property assigned_at and updated_at.
Queries are as below :

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "issue_org_states",
      "range": {
        "assigned_at": {
          "from": "2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2017-10-09T23:59:59.999Z",
          "include_lower": true,
          "include_upper": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run above query its return data. But if run the same query on updated_at instead of assigned_at then elastic search returns 0 result. assigned_at and updated_at both have same mapping and same data till below query not returning any result.

```
    {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "issue_org_states",
      "range": {
        "updated_at": {
          "from": "2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2017-10-09T23:59:59.999Z",
          "include_lower": true,
          "include_upper": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on *elasticsearch 5.4.0* and querying against **issue_org_states.updated_at** and **issue_org_states.assigned_at** works properly. You might want to review your actual command line again.

My queries are below, based on [this document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

```
curl -XGET -u elastic:changeme localhost:9200/issues/issues/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "issue_org_states",
      "query" : {
        "range": {
          "issue_org_states.updated_at": {
            "gte": "2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "le": "2017-10-09T23:59:59.999Z"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'


curl -XGET -u elastic:changeme localhost:9200/issues/issues/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "issue_org_states",
      "query" : {
        "range": {
          "issue_org_states.assigned_at": {
            "gte": "2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "le": "2017-10-09T23:59:59.999Z"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Mapping definition,

```
curl -XPUT -u elastic:changeme localhost:9200/issues -d '{
    "mappings": {
      "issues": {
        "properties": {
          "captured_by": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "captured_on": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "updated_at": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "issue_org_states": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "assigned_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "dateOptionalTime"
              },
              "assigned_by": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "updated_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "dateOptionalTime"
              },
              "updated_by": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}'
```

And same data as you.

```
curl -XPOST -u elastic:changeme localhost:9200/issues/issues -d '{
"id": "13f3bf09-08cb-4464-b326-15872bdb0870",
"description": "Sloppy paint job",
"captured_on": "2017-10-09T09:24:01.928Z",
"captured_by": 1,
"updated_at": "2017-10-09T12:47:22.982Z",
"issue_org_states": [
            {
              "updated_at": "2017-10-09T12:47:22.982Z",
              "updated_by": 1,
              "assigned_at": "2017-10-09T12:47:22.982Z",
              "assigned_by": 1879048240
            }
]
}'
```